# How to prevent data to change on scroll listview in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i am facing a problem .i am changing image on click of listview item 
example ( i am changing start image on from gray to star image)

but when  i am scrolling listview then it set previous image like gray image

i want to know how to prevent to change on scroll

here is my code

```
imglayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Boolean clickable = true;
        String pro_tilte = TitleArray.get(position).toString();
        Iterator itr = bookmarkTitleArray.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            String duplicatetile = itr.next().toString();
            if(pro_tilte.equals(duplicatetile)) {
                im4.setClickable(false);
                clickable=false;
            }
        }

        if(clickable) {
            im4.setClickable(true);
            String title=TitleArray.get(position);
            for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : LoadDataInBackEnd.productpageid.entrySet()) {
                String key = entry.getKey();
                if(key.equals(title)) {
                    gross_page_id= entry.getValue();
                }
            }

            new savebookmark().execute("http://pac2.menaguale.com/api/user/user-bookmark");
            ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)v.getParent();
            // access likecount TextView from feed_item layout

           ImageView imagechange = (ImageView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.Pbookmark);
           imagechange.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the code of the getView() method of your adapter ? I guess the code you posted here belongs to it ?

Answer (score 0):

Any changes that you make to `ListView` items need to be tracked in your adapter.  If you are changing a list item and it is being reverted when scrolled back into view, that means that the state of the item was not captured in your adapter for use in your `getView()` method.

Because `ListView` recycles item views, everything needed to recreate a list item needs to be found somewhere in your adapter/model.

Make sure that that list item model in your adapter has a field that can capture the state of the image, then have your `onClick()` set the state and have `getView()` read the state.